# Laravel email DNS validation fails, when ran in Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, jenkins, dns, lumen

I am having trouble when running Laravel email dns validator on valid emails inside a Docker container. I have these validation rules on user model email field:

```
['email:rfc,dns,spoof', 'required']
```

When seeder is ran, it fails on email validation.
Only error I am getting is that "The email must be a valid email address.". All the emails seeder creates are of form first name dot last name like this: "john.doe@example.com". They all should pass.

The weird thing is my local environment running inside a Debian 11 vagrant VirtualBox works just fine. These problems started, when I tried to run seeders inside a Jenkins pipeline using Docker. I have 2 containers one running MariaDB 10.6 and PHP container running PHP 8.1. Using php:8.1-cli container.

I am suspecting that there is some issue fetching the DNS records, but I am not just getting any proper error message for that. If I remove dns validation from the model seeder will run just fine.

I already tried adding Cloudflare DNS server to PHP container, but it did not seem to change anything.

```
dns:
  - 1.1.1.1
```

I am actually using Lumen 9 but that shouldn't probably matter.

Comment: If they are really using the `example.com` domain, DNS lookups for them should fail.

Comment: Yea it seems so. We have always used example.com as a testing domain. Our seeders generate only example.com emails. In our local older enviroment, that runs on vagrant + virtualbox this validation passes for some reason. That's why this got so complicated. It seems its our local VB environment that is accepting these emails for some reason when they should fail.